# Nsis doesn't see environment variables

Tags: nsis

Here is the part os nsis script (.nsi):

```
!ifndef QTDIR
  !error "Please define QT installation directory via /DQTDIR=C:\qt\4.8.4"
!endif
```

But after executing this command:

```
set QTDIR=C:\path\to\qt
```

the erorr still occurs. The same result on two computers, both windows 7. Nsis version is 2.46 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`!ifdef` and `!ifndef` operate on defines internally in the compiler process. You can set one in your script with `!define` or use the `-D` MakeNSIS command line argument.

MakeNSIS can also read Windows environment variables: `!echo "The value of QTDIR is $%QTDIR%"`.

You can also support both:

```
!ifndef QTDIR
!define QTDIR "$%QTDIR%"
!endif
!if ! /fileexists "${QTDIR}"
!error "QTDIR not valid"
!endif
```